# Unmarshalling Json data into map in Go

Tags: json, go

I am dealing with an api that returns json data such as:

```
    {
  "bpi": {
    "2018-06-01": 128.2597,
    "2018-06-02": 127.3648
  },
  "disclaimer": "something here.",
  "time": {
    "updated": "Sep 6, 2013 00:03:00 UTC",
    "updatedISO": "2013-09-06T00:03:00+00:00"
  }
```

However the price data that has the accompanying dates can return a dynamic date range (ie could be anything from 1 data pair to 1000).

I'm trying to take only the date and price pairs and put them into a map for later consumption, but I'm not finding a straight forward way of doing it. When I put this into a json-to-go auto struct generator it will create a statically and named struct for the pricing.

This is my best attempt at handling the data dynamically. I am passing an empty interface from the response body of the http get, specifically:

`var unstructuredJSON interface{}
 json.Unmarshal(body, &unstructuredJSON)`

and passing the unstructuredJSON to the function:

```
func buildPriceMap(unstructuredJSON interface{}, priceMap map[string]float64) {
jsonBody := unstructuredJSON.(map[string]interface{})

for k, v := range jsonBody {
    switch vv := v.(type) {
    case string:
        // Do Nothing
    case float64:
        priceMap[k] = vv
    case interface{}:
        buildPriceMap(vv, priceMap)
    default:
        log.Fatal("Json unknown data handling unmarshal error: ", k, vv)
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't fully understand your input format. Can you include a couple examples of this "dynamic date range" you're describing?

Comment: @Flimzy in the bpi section I can request from the api a date range so it could be a list of a 100 days of data

Comment: That looks like a simple map. Is there some reason `map[string]float64` won't work for you?

Comment: The current way I have it is working for me but I'm wondering if I'm going about it in an overly complicated fashion.

Comment: The method you have in your question is overly complicated, yes.  Unless there are surprises you haven't described, just unmarshal to a struct with a field like this:  `BPI map[string]float64`

Comment: Got it I'll give it a try. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your JSON is not unstructured or dynamic.

Comment: No JSON is unstructured. JSON is the structure. If it's unstructured, it's not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you know the top level keys, e.g. `bpi`, `disclaimer`, `time` etc and that the "dynamic data pairs" that you are talking about are part of the `bpi` field, and that the key and value types of each of the members of `bpi` are always `string: decimal number` you do something like....

```
type APIResp struct {
    BPI        map[string]float64 `json:"bpi"`
    Disclaimer string
    // other fields
}
```

Now each of your pairs will be typed correctly and contained in the `APIResp.BPI` map. Unmarshal as you are doing already;

```
var r APIResp
err := json.Unmarshal(body, &r)
// TODO: check err
```